# How to resolve "Trouble accessing your contacts account (ZB)" in Google Pay

Tags: android, google-pay

I am deep-linking my app with google Pay. While making a transaction through Google Pay, it gives the response **Trouble accessing your contacts account (ZB)**

```
StartPaymentServiceImpl: Start payment failed, not updating default payment instrument.
bge: abbm: FAILED_PRECONDITION: Precondition check failed.
    at bgi.a(Unknown Source:3)
    at srz.a(SourceFile:2)
    at tvs.a(SourceFile:2)
    at tvr.run(SourceFile:6)
    at tya.execute(Unknown Source:0)
    at tvu.b(SourceFile:4)
```

Comment: How are you doing this? What is the deeplink you are using?